# Como a Microsoft conseguiu personalizar o estilo do título da aba?

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome

Olhando a [nova página da Microsoft para o Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/features), pelo menos no Ubuntu 14 / Chrome 43, percebi que o tamanho da fonte da aba estava maior que a fonte das demais abas abertas. Já no Firefox 38, isso não acontece.

---

[image: "Recursos do Win[...]" aparece maior que os demais títulos.]

***"Recursos do Win[...]" aparece maior que os demais títulos.***

---

Alguém mais consegue reproduzir este comportamento? Seria um bug?

Dei uma olhada nas propriedades do DOM da página, mas não consegui entender porque isso aconteceu.

Comment: No Chrome 43 (Windows) não consegui reproduzir, já no Chromium 41 (Ubuntu 15) aconteceu a mesma coisa.

Comment: De fato parece ser um bug, não consegui reproduzir em nenhum navegador também. Windows e Ubunto não combinam. kkk

Comment: Deve ser bug, então... O estranho é: QUANDO ele acontece? Outras abas no mesmo site não ficam assim...

Comment: É bug do ChomeRAM para Linux, testei no Opera e está normal